# How to show that if $f(x) = g(x)-g(0)$ where $g$ is linear then $\lim_{x\searrow 0} f'(x) = g'(0)$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Is it just a straightforward application of the definition of derivative (using the fact that $g$ is linear, hence differentiable everywhere)?

I.e., is it just that

$$f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = g'(x)$$

and then just use the fact that $$\lim_{x\searrow 0} g'(x) = g'(0)$$

**(I am particularly unsure of this last step**. Is this true because $g$ is linear and hence has a derivative everywhere?

If, instead, $g$ was not linear, but had a kink, i.e. $g(x) = \vert x \vert $, then would we just replace $g'(0)$ with the limit of this derivative from the right?

Comment: Nitpick: in your derivative, h goes to zero, not x.

Comment: And indeed: since g is linear, its derivative is continuous and for a continuous function $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =f(a) $.

Comment: Also, note that f itself is linear, hence differentiablr'e everywhere :)